# solidity contract creation factory contract method is being called, but new contract is not getting created

Tags: solidity, truffle, ganache, solidity-0.8.x

I have two seperate contracts:

1. `SuperAdmin.sol`
2. `User.sol`

And they look like this:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "./User.sol";

contract SuperAdmin {
  address[] public users;

  constructor() {}

  modifier restricted() {
    if (msg.sender == address(this)) _;
  }

  function addNewUser(address adminAddress) public restricted returns(address) {
    address newUser = User(adminAddress).getAddress();
    users.push(newUser);
    return newUser;
  }
}
```

And the other contract, looks like this:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.7;


contract User {
  address private partner;
  address private admin;

  constructor(address _admin) {
    partner = msg.sender;
    admin = _admin;
  }

  modifier restricted() {
    if (msg.sender == address(this)) _;
  }

  function getAddress() external view returns(address){
      return address(this);
  }

  function interact() restricted view{
    // do something
  }
}
```

Now, let me tell you about the purpose, `SuperAdmin` will be able to create `User`s, which is done by `addNewUser` in `SuperAdmin`.

But the issue is in my Ganache, I'm getting only **Contract Call**, but no **Contract Creation**, which is quite unexpected. At least I thought it would work a factory to create contracts.

[image]

**And the `address[] public users;` is also not being modified. Pretty odd.**

Even after adding `new` keyword, it's not creating a new contract / deploying a new contract as expected.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use `new`  keywork in your `addNewUser` function:

```
   User newUser;

   function addNewUser(address adminAddress) public restricted returns(address) {
    newUser= new User(adminAddress)
    users.push(address(newUser));
    return newUser;
  }
}
```

Comment: Even after adding the `new` keyword a new contract is not being deployed. Please look: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SZLy.png